# Access Token Authentication w/ Devise, Omniauth & Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I have my app correctly set up to associate a Dropbox Oauth login with a user (via Devise/Omniauth).  The folder under `Dropbox/Apps/myapp` is correctly made.

I've saved (and encrypted) the user's access token & access secret in the database - how do I use OmniAuth to authenticate using these values instead of them going through the full Dropbox OAuth cycle?  Every time I log in using Dropbox it is asking me over and over if I'd like to allow the app access to my Dropbox folder.

I have set up the OmniAuth callbacks pretty much just as they are in the wiki.  It searches for the provider & uid, and finds the user that way.  Is this something different with how Dropbox works vs. Twitter or Facebook?  They only ask me once to associate the Twitter/FB account with `myapp`.

Answer (score 1):

hmm,hi, if u tried to connect every users  with your dropbox, then it will ask the permission to access your folder. Basically ,it is just same like facebook App which if you need to access the app, you wil get some request permission. What you need to do maybe is your web application get the access to the dropbox folder for the first time and your users are using it with the privilege you assign for them. Hope it helps..

Comment: I'm not connecting every user with my Dropbox. I'm creating a folder on *each* user's Dropbox (i.e. `~/Dropbox/Apps/myapp`) that I can use to store files and sync with my web application.  What I would like to happen is: **first login** - Dropbox asks if user wants to allow my app to link with their Dropbox.  **second login** if user is logged in to Dropbox on their computer, it goes straight through to my app.  If they are not logged in to Dropbox, they are directed there to login, and then are redirected back to my app (as a logged in user).

Comment: hmm, not really understand ,mayb cz lack of knowledge in the area, i upvote it to get more attention..